# RevSlider Youtube video mute delayed

Tags: wordpress, youtube, revolution-slider

I have a WP site with Revolution Slider auto-playing a full-screen YouTube video on the homepage.

I selected the mute option for the video in the settings, however, the audio plays for 1 second on load! It literally sounds like a glitch.

How do I fix this?

Comment: were you able to figure it out? Daaamn I'm having the same issue. I even set the volume from 100 to 0 but the issue is still there. :p

Comment: Sorry I didn't find solution for the problem